# What software can I use to find and manage duplicate files (docs & photos) on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: osx, duplicate-files, macbook

I'm on a Macbook Pro with Mac OS Sierra (10.12.5) and I'm looking for software which can identify, manage and delete duplicate files stored in different folders on my mac. Library folders too, if possible. The software must do this for photos (jpg, png, psd) and other documents (txt, docx, pdf) etc.

I don't mind paying for it (but, preferably free), as long as it's not too much. No monthly payment and a maximum of ±€30,-.

If you need any more specs, feel free to ask :-)

Edit: I've come across MacPaw Gemini (and 'CleanMyMac', but that's another topic), but I've heard mixed reviews about them (such as it not being as good for your system as it proposes to be). Any comments on those programs?

Answer (score 1):

I used Duplicate File Finder recently and it worked well and was extremely fast. Pretty simple to use, just drag a folder onto specified area after opening.  This app was free and available from the App Store.  It doesn't do photos though. There are several mentioned on the internet but I've never tested them myself. Hope this helps with files though.

Lifehacker, a magazine type internet site that often rates Mac or iPad software rated Gemini as its top duplicate file finder. It also had the following statement: "If there’s just something about Gemini’s interface you don’t like, The Duplicate Finder ($10) does just about everything Gemini does with a slightly different interface." Don't know if that is the same as the one I tried or not.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend `Duplicate Photos Fixer Pro`. It works good for me. But be patient when using `Similar Matches` because this feature can produce wrong result. You will need to manually check all photos.

Other software which I use in parallel:

- Duplicate Manager Pro
- Duplicate Photos Fixer Pro
- Photos Duplicate Cleaner
- Gemini

Answer (score 1):

[Dupguru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru) is now Freeware  and makes a really good Job.